Не загружается JS без обновления страницы
Сделал переход между страницами без перезагрузки. Теперь, когда я подключил виджеты с Telegram, при переходе с одной страницы (index.html) на другую (archive.html) JS-скрипт не показывается, пока не обновлю страницу. Можно как то заставить JS активироваться без перезагрузки страницы?


import Swup from 'https://unpkg.com/swup@4?module';
const swup = new Swup();
/* Определите продолжительность перехода во время посещения страницы. */
html.is-changing .transition-fade {
    transition: opacity 0.25s;
    opacity: 1;
}

/* Определите стили для выгруженных страниц. */
html.is-animating .transition-fade {
    opacity: 0;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="/css/swup.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="module" src="/js/swup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <main id="swup" class="transition-fade">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <a href="/index.html">Page2</a>
    <script async src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?22" data-telegram-share-url="https://testtest" data-comment="Test" data-size="large"></script>
  </main>
</body>
</html>




Как вставить  через innerHtml в javascript?

как сделан переход между страницами?

Через swup скрипт

добавь пример кода в вопрос

Common Issues & Troubleshooting: Scripts on the next page are not executed

Помог [коментарий],(Не загружается JS без обновления страницы), спасибо.
Оставлю, если у кого то будет такая проблема.
Swup JS:

Scripts on the next page are not executed\
Swup doesn't insert new script tags by default. To run code after a page visit, you have a few options that are explained in the section on Reloading Scripts.\

Trigger custom code using hooks
Use the Head Plugin to insert new scripts into the head
Use the Scripts Plugin to run existing and new scripts in head or body



добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.
